# Excel VBA: Return first unhidden column from the left?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to get the column number of the first unhidden column?

> So if Column A is hidden, return 2.
>    If Column A and B are hidden, return 3.
>    If A and C are hidden, return 2, etc.

Comment: I'm curious as to how _"Is there a way to get the column number of the first unhidden column?"_ is unclear.  I Googled for a solution to this problem, this question came up in the results, it appears clear to me what is being asked.  Are the guys that voted to close the question familiar with Excel and VBA?   Not being sarcastic, by the way, just genuinely want to understand why this question was closed, to get a better understanding of what is acceptable and what is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub test()

    Dim ColCounter As Integer

    ColCounter = 1
    Do While ColCounter > 0 And ColCounter < 66536
      If Sheet1.Columns(ColCounter).Hidden = False Then
           MsgBox (ColCounter)
           Exit Do
      End If
      ColCounter = ColCounter + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: maximum value of an integer is 32767, so checking for < 65536 is tautological.

Comment: @Tmdean Thanks..I just forget the maxiumn count of column in excel...

Comment: it's 16384 for Excel 2007 and later

Answer (score 4):

Without loops

*Updated: didn't handle cases where the left most columns were hidden. If the no cells test is redundant then Tmdean's shorter solutio is superior*

```
 Sub FirstNonHidden()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
If rng1.Column <> 1 Then
MsgBox rng1.Areas(1).Column
Else
MsgBox "No hidden cells"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is probably

```
Dim column_num As Long
column_num = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Column
```

Using a loop would be bit more efficient, though, like bhuang3's solution, but it could be made a little simpler.

```
Dim cursor As Range, column_num As Long
Set cursor = Range("A1")
Do Until cursor.ColumnWidth > 0
    Set cursor = cursor.Offset(0, 1)
Loop

column_num = cursor.Column
```

Comment: This returns a column regardless of any cells being hidden or not.

Comment: Yeah... that's what it's supposed to do based on my reading of the question...

Comment: +1. On further thought I agree

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

EDIT

Proof that is does work
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately does not work

Comment: Works for me.  Please explain what problem you encountered.

Comment: It returns 1 no matter what